# Displaying a non modal dialog in c# and getting a callback when the form is close

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a User Control called MembersList which gives the user the ability to search for members and then the members who qualify based on search criteria are displayed in a grid. The user then can click an edit button or double click the row and then a modal member edit form is displayed. the user edits or views the member information and then closes the edit form and can search for another member. now i want to display the member edit form as non modal. Now i know i will call the Member Edit form with the Show method instead of the ShowDialog method. But how do I know when the user has closed the Member Edit form so the MembersList user control can re-display the grid to reflect any changes made in the edit form. How do i provide the Member Edit form with a callback method on the user control to call when the form is closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can take multiple approaches here.

1. Register an event to Form Closing and perform your actions of updating the grid within the Form Closing.

*Stub code for Form Closing.*

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.FormClosing += form_FormClosing;

void form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the properties from the form and update your grid.
}
```

You will need to maintain properties in your Form2 to identify if the OK button was clicked or the Cancel button was clicked.

2. Pass a delegate to the Form being opened and on button click call the delegate, which will update the grid.
3. Have a custom event on Form2, subscribe to this event from the parent form and in the event handler update your grid.
4. Have a public method in Form1 that can be called on the OK click of Form2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified solution

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2(this);
        form.Show();
    }

    internal void NotifyClosed(Form2 form2)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Closed");
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 _form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.NotifyClosed(this);
    }

}
```